# Creating EKCalendar IOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, eventkit, ekeventkit

I use to EventKit to create EKCalendar.
I try to create it using this method. when I test it in Simulator calendar creates (screenshot) and appears in default Calendar, but when I do the same on device it doesn't work, there are no errors , all the same but without result.  [image]

```
-(void)createCalendar{
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKCalendar *calendar = [EKCalendar    calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:eventStore];
calendar.title = @"my calendarik";

// Iterate over all sources in the event store and look for the local source
EKSource *theSource = nil;
for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources) {
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal) {
        theSource = source;
        break;
    }
}
NSString    *iden = calendar.calendarIdentifier;

if (theSource) {
    calendar.source = theSource;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: Local source not available");
    return;
}

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL result = [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
if (result) {
    NSLog(@"Saved calendar to event store.");

} else {
    NSLog(@"Error saving calendar: %@.", error);
}
   EKCalendar* calendar_;


    NSArray *allCalendars = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    for (EKCalendar *cal in allCalendars) {
    if ([cal.calendarIdentifier isEqualToString:iden]) {
                        calendar_ = cal;
                           break;

            }

else {
        calendar_ = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:iden];
    }
   }
```

`

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Please explain what should happen and what is happening. Are you getting any errors? What have you done to fix the issue?

Comment: I corrected my question.